# Convert Meteor project to simple static site

Tags: meteor, static-site

I'm aware of Meteor's server-side rendering and `spiderable` packages, but neither of those really address my issue.

I like Meteor so much that I want to use it as my primary development environment even for static brochure-style sites (which don't even connect to any dynamic sources).

I would like to have access to all Meteor's features (such as collections and packages) during my dev process though and only convert the whole thing to a static "brochure" when I'm done.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yep. Do everything you would do with Meteor. Collections, reactivity, templating... Then deploy it. On the deployed page, type Ctrl + S. Open the HTML, strip the `script` tag linking to the compiled JS file. Then deploy the HTML and the CSS on any web server.

Comment: You'll lose any JS based events, but otherwise, sounds like a perfect suggestion.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work at all. The only thing on the deployed HTML page is script tags.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-static-blog